# Get height of a div with nested absolute divs with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, nested, height

I've got a a div acting as a container which is positioned as relative.
Within this div I have 3 other divs positioned as absolute.

```
<head>
      <style>
           #container{ position:relative; }
           #block1, #block2, #block3 { position:absolute; }
           #block2 { top:100px; }
           #block3 { top:600px; }
     </style>
</head>
<div id="container">
     <div id="block1"> some text </div>
     <div id="block2"> some text </div>
     <div id="block3"> some text </div>
</div>
```

How can I get correct height of a relative div with js.

I tried .clientHeight and jquery .height() but won't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't the correct height 0px?

Comment: Are you triying to get the height of the container or the absolute divs?

Comment: Yes, it is but how can I get 620px. 600px(top of block3) + 20px(height of a block3 div).

Answer (score 1):

I think you got something wrong. When you position divs inside other divs like that, the container-div will have nearly no (or no) height at all. That's cause of the absolute positioned divs. They can be placed "outside" the container-div, and only use it as a reference for x and y offsets.